# Get shard id for given value of sharding key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I have two replica sets in sharding cluster with documents sharded by `userId` field.

Is there any way to query which shard (replica set) is containgin given document (by `_id` or sharding key filed) without reimplemnting shadring key hashing on client side

Comment: Are you trying to find the value for a hashed shard key or asking a more general question about finding the shard where a given document lives? Can you edit your question with some more info on what you are looking for as well as the specific version of MongoDB you are using? The answer for both hashed shard key and shard(s) used for a query can be found in the explain plan output. For example: `db.users.find({userId:123}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan`. The MongoDB 4.0+ shell also has a `convertShardKeyToHashed()` helper.

Comment: @Stennie its "question about finding the shard where a given document lives", will try `convertShardKeyToHashed` when come back to work

Comment: In that case you don't need `convertShardKeyToHashed()` since the shard name can be more directly found via explain output. The `indexBounds` in the explain output for a query on a hashed shard key value will also indicate the hashed value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use query `explain()` to identify the shard for a document, by querying based on the shard key.

The winning plan should have a SINGLE_SHARD stage with an equality query similar to the following (with some extra output trimmed for clarity):

```
> db.users.find({userId:123}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan
{
    "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
    "shards" : [
        {
            "shardName" : "shard01",
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "test.users",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                "userId" : {
                    "$eq" : 123
                }
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

If you only want the shard name, you can use JavaScript notation to reference the full path:

```
> db.users.find({userId:123}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan.shards[0].shardName
shard01
```

Comment: Hi @Stennie... I have a question. I have 20 millions records in my database and this is my query https://mongoplayground.net/p/zsQ_lmnUr3z. It gives me a field `data` as you can see in the output. Now this is different for each 20 million records. I need to sort with the `data` field and need to find the first 5 records. Can I make indexing on the dynamic field? I will surely raised a question if this question would have an answer

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet This would be best discussed as a separate question including more details of your use case (server version, desired output, and any errors/issues encountered). It is not possible to index calculated fields within the same pipeline but you could output your agg results to a collection with indexes. Note: if your goal is just to get the first `n` matches after adding some calculated values, there is a [`$sort` +  `$limit` memory optimisation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-limit-memory-optimization) so only the top `n` items are kept.

Comment: Hi Stennie please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54630076/sort-on-dynamic-added-field