# Sort on dynamic added field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I have 20 Millions documents in my database with the following manner.

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bb84e931cb3d25a3b21d14e"),
    "merchant": "menswearhouse.com",
    "category": "Fashion > Clothing > Men's Clothing",
    "feature": [
      "-0.899652959529",
      "-0.02401520125567913",
      "0.08394625037908554",
      "0.06319021433591843",
      "-0.015963224694132805"
    ]
  }
```

Now I have below array with which I need to find documents.

```
const dummy = [
  "-0.899652959529",
  "-0.02401520125567913",
  "0.08394625037908554",
  "0.06319021433591843",
  "-0.015963224694132805"
];
```

I need to

1. Find difference of all the values i.e need to subtract first index of `feature` with the first index of my dummy array and so on for the all 5 values.
2. Take square of all values
3. Add all 5 values
4. Take square root.
5. Sort all the values with that field and get only 5 documents.

I am using this query which `$project`s the field when I use `$limit`. But I need to `$sort` with the `$project`ed field and need to take top 5 documents. But there are 20 millions document it doesn't return anything and last forever.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $project: {
    field: {
      $sqrt: {
        $sum: {
          $map: {
            input: { $range: [0, { $size: '$feature' }] },
            as: "d",
            in: {
              $pow: [
                {
                  $subtract: [
                    { $toDouble: { $arrayElemAt: [dummy, "$$d"] }},
                    { $toDouble: { $arrayElemAt: ["$feature", "$$d"] }}
                  ]
                },
                2
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Can I use index on the field which is being created at the runtime?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Could you provide you current collection indexes ?

Comment: Hi @JonathanMuller I did not create any indexes now. Do I need to create?

Comment: As it is, it won't help a lot. I asked to have more context to prepare an answer. Your problem is complex

Comment: Few more questions: can you detail "Add all 128 values" ? "Take square of all values" => Square of values contained in "feature" array or square of all differences between "features" and "dummy" array ?

Comment: "feature" and "dummy" arrays are always containing 5 elements ?

Comment: @JonathanMuller `can you detail "Add all 128 values"` Sorry I have only 5 values. All the 5 points mentioned above has been done using the above aggregation but the problem is at last it creates a dynamic `field` which is obtained by the above calculation and since there are 20 million documents the process is too slow. It works if I put the `$limit` but don't work without the `$limit`. And also I need only 5 documents after the above calculation. So **my final question can I create an index on the dynamic created field ??**

Comment: No. On the documentation, they recommend to place a $match filter in the aggregation as early as possible to use indexes and limit the amount of rows that you process. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipeline-optimization

. As a side note, if you place an index on "feature" it will help a little bit as MongoDB will not require to load the data from the disk if it is not in memory.

If you have a way to first limit the amount of items concerned (like after step 1, if sum of values < 1 could be a filter) it would help a lot.

Comment: It is not possible to index a dynamic field. Are values for dummy field limited ? Would it make sense to pre calculate and store the values for different dummy fields like dummy1, dummy2 etc along with the document ? Now you can index dummy1, dummy2 etc and you can sort based on dummy value you get as input.

Comment: @Veeram Field/Length of the `dummy` is limited but may vary. I cannot pre calculate the array values. This  values are the dimensions of an image and that's why I made my schema like this. Is there any other work around?

Comment: Do you want to do it on run-time?

Comment: @Imran Is there any other way to do?

Comment: in my suggestion you should perform calculation while saving document in new attribute, or if already records are stored do it with job,

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  You can NOT create index on the fields created at runtime.  MongoDB, at this writing, can't achieve what you want.  But you can calculate them in parallel.  Assuming your server has proper resources (CPU and memory), you can, in your application, divide your jobs and execute them in parallel.  For simple math, let's assume you have 20,000,000 (mil) docs and you divide them into 20 tasks.  For each task, it'll process 1,000,000 docs and return top 5 results.  The pipeline for the first task will be

```
[
    {
        '$sort': {
            '_id': 1
        }
    }, {
        '$skip': 0
    }, {
        '$limit': 1000000
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'field': {
                '$sqrt': {
                    <do your thing>
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$limit': 5
    }
]
```

After all threads (tasks) returned, merge the results (only 100 docs) in your application, sort them by `field`, and finally get your top 5 documents.  Note that you have to consider your hardware resources to come up the optimal number of divided tasks.

Comment: 20 tasks with 100,000 docs and 1 task with 2,000,000 docs what difference does it make?

Comment: @Profer, the key is to run 20 tasks concurrently.  You have to use a programming language supporting multi-threading or async.